# Finding an email address from a website

Tags: python, regex

I can find basic email addresses with this:

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+"
```

But how can I find email addresses like:

```
test(at)test.com
foo[at]bar.com
bar@foo.com
```

Comment: [\w-\+\.]+(?:[\(\[]at[\)\]]|@)[\w\-]+\.[\w\-\.]+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+(@|\[at\]|\(at\))[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/aH6cN7/1

---

Here is the regex that accepts spaces before/after the [@t]

```
"([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+\s?(@|\[at\]|\(at\))\s?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/aH6cN7/2

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly.

Could edit it a bit to make it also work with possible spaces o neach side of the @, (, ), [, ] signs? Like: test @ mail.com, my[at] mail.com & your (at)mail.com. Please leave the original answer visible too so I can compare the two and learn. :)

Comment: I'm out of the but you can try to play with this expression '\s?' before or/and after the @.